# CSS Transition on JS createElement() Working Intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using JavaScript to create a div and I'm adding `transition: .5s linear top;`

`onmousedown`, the div is supposed to move to the top and then it is deleted using JS `remove()`. Sometimes the transition works, sometimes not.

I suspect that something in the JS is causing it ... What am I missing?

```js
var redBox = document.createElement("div"),
    intSet;

document.onmousedown = function(){
  intSet = setInterval("animate()", 1000);
}

document.onmouseup = function(){
  clearInterval(intSet);
}

function animate(){
  redBox.classList.add("redBox");
  document.body.appendChild(redBox);

  setTimeout (function() {
    redBox.style.top = "0";
  },0); 

  setTimeout (function(){
    redBox.remove(redBox.selectedIndex);
  },500);
}
```

```css
.redBox{
  background:red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s linear top;
}
```

Comment: replace `setTimeout (function() { redBox.style.top = "0"; },0);` with `redBox.scrollWidth; redBox.style.top = 0;`

Comment: And besides that: `setInterval("animate()", 1000)` -> `setInterval(animate, 1000)`. This is better

Comment: @Thomas So should I use `setTimeout (function() { redBox.scrollWidth; redBox.style.top = 0;},0);`

Comment: the `setTimeout` has in this case no (significant) effect. You can replace it with the code inside the function. And `redBox.scrollWidth;` will do the trick/fix your problem, because it triggers an immediate render-cycle.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! It's working now. I kind of knew that `setTimeout(fn, 0)` was not the best way to do it. I'm glad I know a better way now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Thanks to @Thomas.

```js
var redBox = document.createElement("div"),
    intSet;

document.onmousedown = function(){
  intSet = setInterval("animate()", 1000);
}

document.onmouseup = function(){
  clearInterval(intSet);
}

function animate(){
  redBox.classList.add("redBox");
  document.body.appendChild(redBox);

    redBox.scrollWidth;
    redBox.style.top = "0";


  setTimeout (function(){
    redBox.remove(redBox.selectedIndex);
  },500);
}
```

```css
.redBox{
  background:red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s linear top;
}
```

I replaced the `setTimeout(function(){},0);` with `redBox.scrollWidth;`. The CSS animation is now running smoothly ;)